# How can you make two different NLog targets with same date inside?

Tags: asp.net-core, nlog

I have the following two targets defined in NLog.config inside my ASP.NET Core project:

```
<targets>
    <target name="MyApp" xsi:type="File"
        fileName="${specialfolder:folder=ApplicationData}/MyApp/${date:format=yyyyMMdd_HHmmss:cached=true}_MyApp.log"
        layout="${longdate}|${level:uppercase=true}|${logger}|${message}"
        deleteOldFileOnStartup="false"/>
    <target name="MyAppAll" xsi:type="File"
        fileName="${specialfolder:folder=ApplicationData}/MyApp/${date:format=yyyyMMdd_HHmmss:cached=true}_MyApp.log"
        layout="${longdate}|${level:uppercase=true}|${logger}|${message}"
        deleteOldFileOnStartup="false"/>
</targets>
```

MyApp target logs all my logs from the app while MyAppAll includes some framework logs as well.

I am trying to get the NLog to create two log files that have the same timestamp but what  I have observed is that MyAppAll will be created immediately on app start since this is the time framework logs start while MyApp will only be created once I send request to API and the result is that I have two files with different dates.

Any ideas on how to solve this?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `${processinfo:StartTime}`:

```xml
<targets>
    <target name="MyApp" xsi:type="File"
        fileName="${specialfolder:folder=ApplicationData}/MyApp/${processinfo:StartTime:format=yyyyMMdd_HHmmss:cached=true}_MyApp.log"
        layout="${longdate}|${level:uppercase=true}|${logger}|${message}" />
    <target name="MyAppAll" xsi:type="File"
        fileName="${specialfolder:folder=ApplicationData}/MyApp/${processinfo:StartTime:format=yyyyMMdd_HHmmss:cached=true}_MyApp.log"
        layout="${longdate}|${level:uppercase=true}|${logger}|${message}" />
</targets>
```

See also: https://github.com/NLog/NLog/wiki/ProcessInfo-Layout-Renderer

Notice having 2 file-targets sharing the same filename is not recommended. Forexample with NLog 5 where `KeepFileOpen=true` by default, then one will stop working.